# Keep only columns in Pandas Dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Height of Person': [5.1, 6.2, 5.1, 5.2],
        'Qualification': ['Msc', 'MA', 'Msc', 'Msc'],
        'Country is': ['US', 'UK', 'GE', 'ET']     
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

I would like to specify columns that should remain in the dataframe based on a number of strings that are present in the index.

E.g. Keep those columns whose index contain "Name" or "Country" should result in:

```
data2 = {'Name': ['Jai', 'Princi', 'Gaurav', 'Anuj'],
        'Country is': ['US', 'UK', 'GE', 'ET']   
       }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
display(df2)
```

I tried using

```
df = df.filter(like=["Name"])
```

but I am not sure how to apply multiple expressions (strings) at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter by name, you can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with a regex:

```
df.filter(regex='Name|Country')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to filter just on columns you can do:

```py
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if x in ['Names', 'Country is']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use .loc and find it clearer to read.

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('Name|Country', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
col_filter = df.columns.str.contains('Name') + df.columns.str.contains('Country')
df.loc[:,col_filter]
```

Result:

```
     Name Country is
0     Jai         US
1  Princi         UK
2  Gaurav         GE
3    Anuj         ET
```